# Symfony2 Locale::getDisplayCountries Error: Class ResourceBundle not found

Tags: php, symfony

I wan to take all country using Locale from simfony2. In my local host everything work fine, but the problem apear when I upload the site on a live host, is throw this error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Locale\Locale;
$countriesArray = Locale::getDisplayCountries('en');
```

Can someone tell me where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I found where was the problem. In the live host I didn't have installed the intl extension